# Animation not working in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have used the below code snippet in my native platform (android) to animate the value, and it works fine in android.

```
 public void setValue(double value) {
        if(this.renderer != null)
        {
            ObjectAnimator anim= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.renderer,"Value",(float)this.value,(float)value);
            anim.setDuration(1500);
            anim.start();
        }

        this.value = value;
    }
```

While try to set the newValue for the `Value` property (of android) from `Xamarin`, it sets the newvalue but animation not working in xamarin.

Am i miss something?

Android callable wrappers (ACW) are needed any time the Android runtime needs to invoke managed code, and are required because there is no way to register classes with Dalvik at runtime.[reference link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/)

So i have tried to declare the `ObjectAnimator anim` earlier and animate the value as below,

```
public void setValue(double value) {
if(this.renderer != null)
{
    anim= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.renderer,"Value",(float)this.value,(float)value);
    anim.setDuration(1500);
    anim.start();
}

this.value = value;
```

}

But the mentioned issue isn't resolved.

Comment: Maybe use the correct method names? Xamarin does not use lower camel case.

Comment: @Cheesebaron, the above mentioned code is in `Android(native)` not in `Xamarin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *ObjectAnimator* is trying to find the method *setValue(float)* on your *Renderer* class.

You need to add the *[Export]* attribute to make it visible to the Java side.

```c#
public class Renderer: Java.Lang.Object
{
    private float _value;
    [Export]
    public float getValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    [Export]
    public void setValue(float value)
    {
        _value = value;
        Log.Debug("TestRenderer", "Value: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to use the *ObjectAnimator* like this:

```c#
var renderer = new Renderer();
var anim = ObjectAnimator.OfFloat(renderer, "value", 0f, 1f);
anim.SetDuration(2000);
anim.Start();
```

See [ObjectAnimator Proxy to Animate TopMargin can't find setting/getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290447/objectanimator-proxy-to-animate-topmargin-cant-find-setting-getter) for more info.