# Can't find native method using JNI error when specifying propertyName in ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to do sliding fragments, as in this code: https://github.com/lucamtudor/Sliding-Fragments

However, when ported over to Xamarin, it gives the error:

```
01-26 18:07:10.943 D/PropertyValuesHolder(17296): Can't find native method using JNI, use reflectionjava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setYFraction' signature='(F)V' in class Ltestappandroid/FractionalLinearLayout;
01-26 18:07:10.943 E/PropertyValuesHolder(17296): Couldn't find setter/getter for property yFraction with value type float
```

The custom animation looks as follows:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="@dimen/slide_up_down_fraction"
    android:propertyName="yFraction"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:duration="@integer/slide_up_down_duration">
</objectAnimator>
```

In my FractionalLinearLayout I have:

```
public float getYFraction()
{
    return mYFraction;
}

public void setYFraction(float yFraction)
{
    mYFraction = yFraction;
    SetY((mScreenHeight > 0) ? (mScreenHeight - yFraction * mScreenHeight) : 0);
}
```

I also added a copy with the first letter uppercased, and C# properties with initial letter both uppercased and not, to be sure, but it's not working (same error).

Are there any problems when trying to reference methods from xml with Xamarin?
The complete code is available here: http://home.harteex.com/TestAppAndroid.zip

Finally, I'm also seeing this, no idea if it's relevant:

```
01-26 18:07:10.853 I/dalvikvm(17296): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>, referenced from method testappandroid.FractionalLinearLayout.<init>
01-26 18:07:10.853 W/dalvikvm(17296): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 233: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
01-26 18:07:10.853 D/dalvikvm(17296): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `[Export]` attribute to your getters and setters.

```c#
[Export]
public float getYFraction()
{
    return mYFraction;
}

[Export]
public void setYFraction(float yFraction)
{
    mYFraction = yFraction;
    SetY((mScreenHeight > 0) ? (mScreenHeight - yFraction * mScreenHeight) : 0);
}
```

See: [ObjectAnimator Proxy to Animate TopMargin can't find setting/getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290447/objectanimator-proxy-to-animate-topmargin-cant-find-setting-getter)